# what is meant by action="#main_body" in a HTML form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have form and some fields and I want send these fields to the next page via `done.php` using `action="#main_body"`.

What are the differences between these two forms?

```
<form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="/ifs/form/index.php" method="post">

<form id="formElem " class="ifs"  method="post" action="#main_body">
```

Comment: Unless your form is part of done.php, use `action="path/to/done.php"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the first case you send the values of your inputs to a specific page called done.php. In the second way you're calling the same page in which you have your form (plus an hashtag)

Comment: so i want to go no next page with all my form fields using action="#main_body" is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

The complete action of the form is the URL of the page containing the form at the time of loading the form + the hashtag. So submitting the form will load the same page, but with a ahashtag (anchor) of #man_body. This is a side effect of action attributes being realtive if not definitly given as absolute.

Please be aware, that it is browser-dependant and header-dependant wether the page will actually reload or just scroll.

Comment: so i want to go no next page with all my form fields using action="#main_body" is it possible?

Comment: If by "next page" you mean "next scroll page", than yes. If you mean next request, then it  has the same URL, the correct code, and the current page the headers to force a reload.

Answer (score 2):

In the second link you are calling the same page with a hashtag of "main_body". it will work something like a '**TOP**' link provided in lengthy pages which scrolled back to top of the page.
a difference is here the page will scroll(or reload) to "main_body" when you submit the form.

Comment: so i want to go no next page with all my form fields using action="#main_body" is it possible?